# Drupal 8 Migrate API File to Media Entites

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to perform a migration of Drupal 7 files into Drupal 8 Media entity via Migrate API.

Is there a practical guide how to perform such types of migrations?
Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, the core built-in migration support for Media is still [in the work](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2835825).

However, there are several contrib modules could help you with the migration.

- [Migrate File Entities to Media Entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_file_to_media)
- [Media migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_migration)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The core feature for migrate API is still in the process. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2835825

However there is a drupal contrib module which you can use.

https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_file_to_media